# Manipulate date inside react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I was wondering if there is any way to manipulate a date returned from an API inside the react-table component?

For example, the timestamp comes back from the API formatted as such `2019-08-31 06:27:14` ... What I would like it to look like is something like `Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM`

I am using the react-table component to render the table and the column i would like to manipulate is the `Signup Date` column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
columns={[
    {
        Header: "ID",
        accessor: "id",
        show: false
    },
    {
        Header: "Signup Date",
        accessor: "signup_date"
    }
]}
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you just need a way to transform your timestamp?

Comment: Is it possible there is some function that I can use in the `columns` section of the react-table to do it?

Comment: Yes you can use a [function based accessor](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/515)

Comment: Hey @HMR ... I tried using the example you showed, but im getting `Error: A column id is required if using a non-string accessor for column above.` ... It looks like it cant find `d.signup_date` ... Is there any chance you could show me an example? Im kind of new to all this

Comment: Have you tried giving the cololum(s) a unique id property?

Comment: @HMR ... Oh that seems to have worked adding a unique ID ... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can modify it like this:

```
columns : {[
    {
        Header:"Signup Date",
        accessor:"signup_date",
        //this is the func your looking for, it can retuen custom tableCell
        Cell : (props)=>{
            //props.value will contain your date
            //you can convert your date here
            const custom_date = 'custom_date'+props.value
            return <span>{custom_date}</span>
        }
    }
]}
```

As another solution, it might be a good idea to wrap your table inside a parent container that delivers modified data to table. sth like this:
container.js

```js
componentDidMount(){
    const {data} = this.props;
    let tableData = []
    for(let me in data){
        let object = {
            //select and modify data from incoming server data
            date : 'fake date'
        }
        tableData.push(object)
    }
    this.setState({
        data : tableData
    })
}
render(){
    return(
        <React-Table
           //...settings
           data = {this.state.data}
        />
    )
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: You should use a `setState` in did mount instead of mutating props, mutating props is not a good idea. In render you can use `this.state` to pass as props to the react table.